# How did debuggers work?

Tags: debug

**(Note: I am referring to *software* that would run on an *end-users'* system, not special debugging computers)**

Debuggers are programs that poke around at other programs' memory. In modern computers they rely on the ability for multiple programs to run at once, abundance of memory and, most importantly, dynamic allocation: an ordinary program only having access to memory it's reserved, which other programs can't simultaneously use for different purposes.

However, retro-computers didn't have these features: except using interrupts (passing control back and forth), programs couldn't run simultaneously. Programs had access to all the memory: there was no way to tell what memory was and wasn't used, therefore knowing where to load the debugger. And even if there was a way to know that, many programs used most or all of the memory in a computer, leaving no place for the debugger to run.

And yet debugging software *did* exist, such as the DDT series, the ODT series, OLIVER, SIMON, CA/EZTEST and much of the XPEDITER series. My question is: how did they work?

- How did they load themselves into memory without conflict?
- How did they implement single-stepping?
- How did they ensure that they weren't overwritten?

Comment: This seems overly broad -- every retro system could have a different solution. The Apple II had in-memory debuggers that trapped BRK, the Apple IIgs had debugging boards with NMI buttons, the SNES had development hardware and ICEs, etc.

Comment: @fadden Couldn't there be an answer along the lines of "it depends" then describing how several systems would do it? (Although two of your examples are about extra hardware, which is not what I meant so I will clarify)

Comment: The text from the close-vote reads, "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format." Which seems to fit this pretty well.

Comment: This is an interesting question but it's way too broad: there were (and are) many different types of debuggers (ICEs, built-in monitors, debuggers relying on help from the CPU...), explaining them all doesn't fit within the scope here. There was even a system with a physical crank which controlled single-stepping!

Comment: Software debug is fairly likely to take advantage of hardware features built specifically to support debug, so there is a big overlap with system/cpu debug.

Comment: @SeanHoulihane Yes, but software debug won't work on an end-user's system if the debugging is performed on special development hardware.

Comment: I mean just BKPT instruction, data/instruction address comparators, single-step exception - these can be fairly trivial in hardware, so exist in production hardware (at least for some processors).

Comment: @SeanHoulihane And that is what I'm referring to: software that either uses these features, or uses other methods (i.e. interrupts) for similar or the same effect.

Comment: OK, narrow the scope to debug which can run in-system, on unmodified production hardware.  You could then ask differnet Qs about production hardware with dedicated support hardware,  and possibly ICE type solutions  too. Seems I missed the bold text...

Comment: To narrow the scope of the question, I'd suggest reading up on debuggers, and asking specific questions that come up then. For example, what's the use of a certain feature, how was a specific feature implemented... Even limiting this question to software debuggers is rather broad: there are system-level debuggers, interpreter-based debuggers, debuggers running on a second system...

Comment: An example that fits with these comments: single-stepping on a KIM-1. This allowed for, obviously, single-stepping, but it had to be done in a way that handled certain kinds of interrupts, or ROM routines, like... single-stepping would be affected. It was actually very clever.

Comment: Too bad that this question is way too general for SE, but how developers handled debugging on computers and consoles before the early / mid 90s would be very interesting to learn about. Coworker's response: "border color."  Programmers these days have it easy with MMUs and protected memory environments.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 the questions in your update are interesting, but keeping them all together isn't conducive to the best answers. I'd say the memory question (conflicts and preventing overwriting) would work as one question, and the single-stepping one would be nice perhaps as one question per relevant CPU architecture (*i.e.* CPU architectures were you determine it's not obvious how it would work).